# Simple refactoring in Java (Basics)

Tags: java

I have these two constructors for creating BankAccount

```
    public BankAccount(int accountNumber , double balance) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
        this.balance = balance;         
        System.out.println(this.accountNumber+"    "+this.balance);         
    }

    public BankAccount(int accountNumber) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
        this.balance = 0;

        System.out.println(this.accountNumber+"    "+this.balance);
    }
```

I want to refactor it and conform to  `DRY` (don't repeat yourself) principle.I wrote this but it raises an error... please help...

```
public BankAccount(int accountNumber) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        BankAccount(accountNumber,0.0);
    }
        public BankAccount(int accountNumber , double balance) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
        this.balance = balance;

        System.out.println(this.accountNumber+"    "+this.balance);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `this`

```
public BankAccount(int accountNumber) {
    this(accountNumber,0.0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the following code:

```
public class BankAccount {
    int accountNumber;
    double balance;
    public BankAccount(int accountNumber) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this(accountNumber, 0.0);
    }

    public BankAccount(int accountNumber , double balance) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.accountNumber =accountNumber;
        this.balance = balance;

        System.out.println(this.accountNumber+"    "+this.balance);

    }
}
```

It compiles fine. You use `this` with constructors as they are not methods.